# Does Java have a way to assign variable names to new objects from the Scanner class?

Tags: java, object, reference, java.util.scanner

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter name: ");
String name = sc.nextLine(); // works

System.out.println("Start a new application, applicant name: ")
Object?? applicantName = sc.nextObject???; // not sure how to implement
```

I can create new objects in the Main class, but I cannot create new objects using the command line during run-time. The Scanner will pick up datatypes, such as String, but not reference types -- at least not the name of a new Object. How do I use the Scanner to get user input and assign it to the variable name of a new Object?

If my code worked, it would let me type: John

It would output: Applicant John = new Applicant();

Comment: Java doesn't have dynamic variables, if that's what you're trying to do.

Comment: I can assign values to int, String, etc. through Scanner, but I cannot assign a value to a new object. I'm trying to make an instance of a class in the command line, instead of in the Main class. Is that impossible?

Comment: I can populate a constructor function with data from Scanner, but not the constructed object's name. My goal is to create an app that allows new users to create new objects in the UI, and then populate the fields with their subsequent input. I can get everything but the first part.

Comment: You got it a bit wrong. What you want is a `name` field in the `Applicant` class. Then, when you instantiate an applicant object, assign an input String to that field - not the reference variable.

Comment: One easy way to do that is to ask the user for the name of the UI object then do a switch statement on the name to add the correct object. That is not the best way but it would work

Answer (score 2):

Based on what you've said:

> If my code worked, it would let me type: John
>   It would output: Applicant John = new Applicant();

No, you can't do this. Java doesn't support dynamic reference variable names. Though, this raises the question:

Why would you want to name the reference variable based on the input? If you provide some more info, maybe we can help that way.

Comment: I was hoping to let the user control the name of each new object. The new object would be assigned their inputted name. From what you say, maybe I should create a new object apart from their input, or simply create a new object every time they start the process of filling out an application but keep the name private.

Comment: There's no way to let the user control the name of the object, but there is a way to let the user control any of the fields of the object - such as `name`, `age` etc.

Comment: I'm assuming that you want a user to be able to input a `name` for an applicant, and then populate the rest of the information. This is done by passing a String to the constructor that corresponds to the `name` field in the `Applicant` class. Once created, the object's information can be populated using setter methods.

Comment: That's exactly my goal.

Comment: Makes sense. Naming the reference variable doesn't affect the object at all. It's just a human-friendly way to access the memory location in the stack where the object is located in your RAM. Make a constructor in your `Applicant` class that accepts just a `name`. Once initialized, you can add the rest of the info through setter methods. If you need any help, please don't hesitate to ask :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way to change or instantiate variables during run-time, i'm pretty sure you can only do it in the code.

Comment: I don't think this answers the question, and gives wrong (or at least, confusing and misleading) information.